# Convert a .py to .exe including a sqlite3 database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, cx-freeze

I've built a python program using YouTube's API to detect changes on some channels.

Here's how I organized my program :

```
Project/
    classes/
        Database.py
    database/
        project.db
    main.py
```

My main.py program contacts YouTube API a first time, store some informations into the .db file using an instance of my Database class.

Then it contacts YouTube API at a certain time interval and check for differences between what's in the .db file and the server response.

I'm trying to export my project into a .exe to share it with a collegue, but cx_Freeze doesn't work fine for me.

My **main.py**:

```
# IMPORT
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'classes/')
from Database import Database
import urllib.request
import json
import re
```

My **Database.py**:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../database/')
import sqlite3
```

My **setup.py**:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os

build_exe_options = {"packages": ['sys', 'urllib.request', 'json', 're'], "excludes": ["tkinter"], "include_files": ['database/project.db']}

setup(name = 'Project',
    version = '0.1',
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("main.py")])
```

Typing:

```
python3 setup.py build
```

The interesting part of the **result**:

```
running build
running build_exe
...
Missing modules:
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib, importlib.abc
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap,     importlib.abc
? _winapi imported from subprocess
? _winreg imported from platform
? java.lang imported from platform
? msvcrt imported from getpass, subprocess
? nt imported from ntpath, os, shutil
? nturl2path imported from urllib.request
? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle
? os.path imported from os, pkgutil, py_compile, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util
? vms_lib imported from platform
? winreg imported from mimetypes, platform, urllib.request
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.

creating directory build/exe.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/lib
Copying data from package collections...
Copying data from package email...
Copying data from package encodings...
Copying data from package html...
Copying data from package http...
Copying data from package importlib...
Copying data from package json...
Copying data from package logging...
Copying data from package pydoc_data...
Copying data from package sqlite3...
Copying data from package unittest...
Copying data from package urllib...
Copying data from package xml...

...

copying database/project.db -> build/exe.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/project.db
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/objdump: 'database/project.db': The file was not recognized as a valid object file.
fatal error:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: internal objdump command failed
```

The generated folder contains:

```
Project (with the icon "exec" on my system, but no .exe extension)
project.db (not in a database/ folder, just side by side with the rest)
lib/
Python (with the icon "exec" on my system, but no .exe extension)
```

When testing this on its system (Windows 10), first he has to manually add the extension ".exe" to the "Project" file, or else it just appears as a folder, and then when running it, it just says "This application cannot run on your PC".

I don't get why it doesn't work. Do you have any idea, what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `objdump` should never be run because the DB file is not an executable file. This looks like a bug in cx_freeze.

Comment: What should I do ? Re-install cx_freeze ? Using what, brew ?